# Access Apache Spark WebUI running in Vagrant

Tags: apache-spark, vagrant

So I setup a vagrant environment with Spark 1.5.0 installed. Then I use sbin/start-all.sh to start Spark. Inside VM I can curl localhost:8080 to get the HTML content telling Master and worker info etc. But I can't access the webui outside of the Vagrant. However from host machine I can telnet to localhost:8080. Here is my Spark environment:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-1.5.0
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=$SPARK_HOME/work
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=1G
```

Here is my vagrant port forwarding setup:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7077, host: 7077
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

Did I miss anything here? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @user2182349, thanks for the tip. It is a FW issue. I fixed it by adding the proper rules.

Answer (score 0):

With spark 3.2.1 I can access the webUI at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

without changing any default FireWall rule.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).